# Trying to keep two buttons and paragraph on the same horizontal line on same row in table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Picture here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGVHJ.jpg
I essentially want the - button to be directly left of "1" and + to the right of "1".
The rows are being populated with data that is in the model with spring.

```
<table  class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Total Price</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="cartLine : ${cartLines}">
        <td>
        <a  th:href="@{|/product/${cartLine.product.id}|}" th:text="${cartLine.product.title}"></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>
            <form th:action="@{|/cart/decrease/${cartLine.product.id}|}"  method="post">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  id="decreaseCartLine"  value="-"/>
            </form>
            <p th:text="${cartLine.quantity}"></p>
            <form th:action="@{|/cart/increase/${cartLine.product.id}|}"  method="post">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  id="increaseCartLine"  value="+"/>
            </form>
            </p>
        </td>

        <td th:text="${cartLine.product.price}">price</td>
        <td th:text="${cartLine.totalPrice}">total price</td>


        <td><form th:action="@{|/cart/remove/${cartLine.product.id}|}"  method="post">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  id="removeCartLine"  value="Remove Item"/>
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

Check Demo [here](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/ZKmKGM?editors=1100)

Another option without changing your existing code with `table` structure inside `td`

```
<td class="qtyWidth">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <form th:action="@{|/cart/decrease/${cartLine.product.id}|}" method="post">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="decreaseCartLine" value="-" />
              </form>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span class="qtyNumber" th:text="${cartLine.quantity}">11</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <form th:action="@{|/cart/increase/${cartLine.product.id}|}" method="post">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="increaseCartLine" value="+" />
              </form>
            </td>
          </tr>


        </table>
      </td>
```

CSS:

```
.qtyWidth {
  width: 150px;
}
.qtyNumber {
 margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Try with bootstrap feature `input-group` component

Check working demo [here](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/KmrzJE?editors=1010)

HTML:

```
   <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Total Price</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr th:each="cartLine : ${cartLines}">
      <td>
        <a th:href="@{|/product/${cartLine.product.id}|}" th:text="${cartLine.product.title}"></a>
      </td>
      <td class="qtyWidth">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" disabled="disabled" data-type="minus" data-field="quant[1]">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
          </button>
          </span>
          <input type="text" name="quant[1]" class="form-control input-number" value="1" min="1" max="10">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[1]">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
          </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>

      <td th:text="${cartLine.product.price}">price</td>
      <td th:text="${cartLine.totalPrice}">total price</td>


      <td>
        <form th:action="@{|/cart/remove/${cartLine.product.id}|}" method="post">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="removeCartLine" value="Remove Item" />
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.form-control {
  height: auto;
}
.qtyWidth {
  width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: The + and - are supposed to be post request to my server making sure there is enough in stock etc,not sure where to go from that example to doing that

Comment: In demo look for the JS code. there you can edit the code as per your need you can get the value of input by using click event on buttons  then make an AJAX request to update the same.

Comment: Unfortunately rewriting my code to be AJAX(there is other things to update like cart total etc) and my controller for the post request to just make some buttons stay in line doesnt seem like the right solution

Comment: @Daniel Please check the updated answer. I hope it resolves the issue without changing the existing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the three items inside of a bootstrap row?
You can probably optimize this more, but the following seems to display fine for me:

```
  <div class="container fluid" style="max-width: 200px;">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4"><form th:action="@{|/cart/increase/${cartLine.product.id}|}"  method="post"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  id="decreaseCartLine"  value="-"/></div>
    <div class="col-4"><p th:text="${cartLine.quantity}"></p></div>
    <div class="col-4"><form th:action="@{|/cart/increase/${cartLine.product.id}|}"  method="post"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  id="increaseCartLine"  value="+"/></div>
    </form></div>
```

Comment: It is still the same for me

Answer (score 0):

Try without 'p' tag. Because, Paragraph tag generally take full width.

Comment: I changed to a span tag as I need a tag for the th:text="${cartLine.quantity}" and its still the same

Comment: Can you provide me your site link. It will be helpful for me to check what makes the content wrap to the next line.